# Restriction of divisors to the generic fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a fibered surface $X \rightarrow C$, with generic fiber $Y$ and a vector bundle $E$ on $X$.

Then the first Chern class $c_1(E)$ is a divisor on $X$, so one can restrict this divisor to the generic fiber $c_1(E)_{|Y}$.

On the other hand one can restrict $E$ to the generic fiber and look at its first Chern class as a divisor on $Y$, i.e. $c_1(E_{|Y})$.

Do we always have the equality $c_1(E)_{|Y}=c_1(E_{|Y})$ as divisors on $Y$, if $X$, $C$ and $Y$ are "nice" enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, even when $X$, $C$ and $Y$ are as nasty as they can be. Chern classes are functorial.

Comment: Ah thanks. So let me see if i got this: 
I take the inclusion $i : Y \rightarrow X$, then one has $c_1(i^{*}E)=i^{*}c_1(E)$ by functoriality of $c_1$, which is exactly the equality i'm looking for.

Comment: That's exactly right.